# Server 2012 R2: World Wide Web Publishing service is failing to start

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, service

I've got Server 2012 R2 running in Hyper-V with Exchange 2013 installed. It's not a critical system - I'm using it to learn Exchange administration.

I went to log into the server tonight after several months of not touching it, to discover that four services are consistently failing to start no matter what I do. The World Wide Web Publishing Service error seems to be commonly caused by a the `AppPools` folder missing from `C:\inetpub\temp\`, but that is not the case for me - I've already checked twice.

The services are:

- Net.Tcp Listener Adapter
- World Wide Web Publishing Service
- Net.Msmq Listener Adapter
- Net.Pipe Listener Adapter

In the event log are the same four errors over and over:

**Event ID 5036, Source WAS**

> The configuration manager for Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) did not initialize. The data field contains the error number.

The error number listed is `0D000780`.

---

**Event ID 5005, Source WAS**

> Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) is stopping because it encountered an error. The data field contains the error number.

The error number listed is `0D000780`.

---

**Event ID 7023, Source Service Control Manager**

> The Windows Process Activation Service service terminated with the following error:
> The data is invalid.

---

**Event ID 7001, Source Service Control Manager**

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service service depends on the Windows Process Activation Service service which failed to start because of the following error:
> The data is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect you've got malformed XML in your `applicationHost.config` file. I'd give that file a once-over as a first troubleshooting step.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following command

(from `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` or your version):

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -GA domain\username
```

and then restarted IIS.

It seems to be an app pool issue if you sysprep or moved configs

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Evan. You can restore the applicationHost.config from backup. Check here for the process.
https://supertekboy.com/2015/02/16/windows-process-activation-service-will-not-start-error-13-the-data-is-invalid/