# Windows Process Activation Service won't start - Error 2

Tags: windows, iis

IIS stopped working on my machine after recent update of Win 10. From what I see this is because WAS service fails to start with error 2. I believe it's the same issue as described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-process-activation-service-wont-start/e0c9ee4a-7ca1-498f-b03e-c893fbb70147). I've tried many things from answers to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/891302/windows-process-activation-service-failing-windows-10), and reinstalled all features and IIS multiple times, but nothing worked. Anyone knows what else I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To any lost soul who came here for a solution. I spent many hours on this and this is what finally worked for me:

1. Remove machine key files as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/903237/473065).
2. Reinstall all features as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/891538/473065).
3. WAS still didn't want to start. I copied `applicationHost.config` to `applicationHost.config.tmp` and tried start the service again.
   **This finally worked**.

Can't wait for next Windows update to break my dev environment again! So much fun!